# How to get state of SelectBooleanCheckbox in Ajax Listener?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I'm trying to do some action in the ManagedBean based on the state of the checkbox.

Checkbox is here:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cb">
    <p:ajax listener="#{myBB.checkboxChanged}"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

The signature of the listener method is this:

```
public void checkboxChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
```

The listener method is called as expected, but I'm not sure how to get the state of the checkbox(if it is selected)
This is false all the time:

```
((SelectBooleanCheckbox)event.getSource()).isSelected()
```

Do I need to bind the value of the checkbox? I'd like to avoid that, because the checkboxes are generated from enum in a loop and I don't have any boolean where to bind it(the model is designed in a way that I'm adding/removing the instances of enum to a collection, not setting boolean properties)

I'm running the code on Tomcat 6.0.36 with Primefaces 3.5

JSF implementation is Apache Myfaces 2.1.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as expected for me on Mojarra 2.2.1 and PrimeFaces 4.0RC1 as well as Mojarra 2.0.3 and PrimeFaces 3.5. Unfortunately I didn't have 2.1 handy. What version of PrimeFaces are you using? Can you post your complete code?

Comment: I'm using primefaces 3.5 and deploying on Tomcat 6.0.36. What works? The isSelected() gives you correct value?
Oops... I'm not using JSF 2.1 as I thought so.

Comment: isSelected() correctly alternates between true/false when the checkbox is clicked on my test environment. I am deploying on Tomcat 7.0.34.

Comment: So it looks like it's a problem of apache myfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Lucas was right, everything is fine. The problem is I did not put the button in the form.

After adding `<h:form>` tag, everything is ok.

Comment: It is always helpful to create an MCV Example. Otherwise other people would assume, that you have a form.